# JS function hidden element value

Tags: javascript, cgi

I have a hidden element:

```
<input id="enableStat" type="hidden" value="<!--#echo var="enableStat"-->" />
```

I am using this variable to flag if certain feilds were enabled or disabled.

In JS:

```
    if(somecondition==false) 
    {
        document.getElementById('enableStat').value = 0;
        //some other statements
    }  
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('enableStat').value = 1;
        //some other statements
    }
```

I then check for this variale in my CGI:

```
SSPEC_RESOURCE_ROOTVAR("enableStat", sEnable, PTR16, "%s"),       
static char sEnable[2];
if(!strncmp(sEnable, "1", 1))
     //do something
```

Now, what I see is that the value in senable is always 1 no matter what. The if-else statements in JS are executed properly.

To add here, the statements:

```
document.getElementById('enableStat').value = 0; 
document.getElementById('enableStat').value = 1;
```

If I make my question more clearer:
I want to create a variable/element in JS which I can use in CGI. How can I do this. In the above code, there seems to be some syntax mistake or variable name etc.

Comment: what is "somecondition"?

Comment: I check for some other variable values.

Comment: `if(somecondition==false)` -- that's a freaky way to do things. Why not the inverted order of then/else ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding in C/C++ then you should be using `strncmp` to *compare* strings. `strncpy` copies the string and returns the address of the destination, which is an address and therefore won't be 0, so will always evaluate to true...

Comment: The value doesnt get set in CGI